# Why is the value of NUMERIC_SCALE column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table for DATA_TYPE='double' NULL?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have created a column whose data_type is **DOUBLE**.

```
alter table my_table add column my_column double;
```

When I queried about this column in **information_schema.COLUMNS** table
I found that the **NUMERIC_SCALE** for this column is **NULL**?

```
select DATA_TYPE,
NUMERIC_PRECISION,
NUMERIC_SCALE

from information_schema.columns

where table_schema = 'my_schema'
and table_name = 'my_table'
and column_name = 'my_column'

+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| DATA_TYPE | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_SCALE |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| double    |                22 |          NULL |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Floating point* numbers are exactly that -- there's no *fixed* position for the decimal separator (point), it can be anywhere, and specifying scale (i.e. the number of digits after the decimal separator) does not make sense.

Scale is used for the `DECIMAL` data type, a type with the *fixed* decimal separator, for which scale *is* significant and meaningful.

MySQL also allows a non-standard syntax for floating point numbers, where you *can* specify precision and scale, e.g. `DOUBLE(10, 5)`. MySQL will round floating point values to that specification when storing them, and format them appropriately when returning query results.

---

[Documentation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be9ef8774199d2c7e3fbc6dc94fce756).

Comment: I am trying to write a script to copy a table definition from MySQL to Redshift. The datatype in MySQL is of the type floating point. But the corresponding column in Redshift is expected to be a non-floating point. Hence the NULL value of NUMERIC_SCALE column is creating an issue. Maybe I should consider the range of values stored in that column before deciding on the values for PRECISION and SCALE in Redshift-table-definition. Is there any other workaround that you can suggest ?

Comment: You absolutely need to consider the range of existing values. You also need to consider what precision and scale your business requires.

Comment: @SubrataDas - If you were using float/double in MySQL for currency, _that_ is the mistake that needs to be fixed.